# R shiny: how to make an operation based on textInput

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to check if a textInput has been completed, and then run an operation based on this. For some reason, the following simplified code does not work. Is there something wrong ?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("TEST"),
sidebarPanel(

textInput('C1', "","C1")
),

mainPanel(uiOutput("value"))

)

server <- function(input,output){

output$value <- renderUI({
#input$C1

if (is.null(input$C1)){
value <- 0}
else{
value <- 1
}
})

}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: The answer below has given you the solution, but I just want to remind you that `input$C1` will never be `NULL`. When the text input is empty, its value is an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside renderUI must return a "tags" object, that is, a valid html. your code returns 0 or 1, neither of which is a valid return value in that context.
all you need is to enclose the return value in something that creates such code, for example, instead of

```
 value<-0
```

try

```
 h4("0")
```

and everything will be fine.

Comment: Hi Amit. Actually what I would it like is to notice when the textInput is empty (i.e its value is "") and do something based on that. With this solution and my above code, the value is always 1 since is.null will never be true. I've tried different things without success. Do you know any an other way to specify the condition ?

Comment: ah yes, you're right ! this works ! It also works with if (input$C1=='') actually. (I don't know why I did not think about this before). MANY THANKS Amit, this is really appreciated !